# In the USA, how much more expensive is 100LL compared to Jet-A1?

Tags: usa, fuel, cost, refueling

I have never flown an aircraft before and do not have any clue of what the fuel prices are. I was doing some research recently and found that some websites say Jet-A1 costs about 1.5 - 2 dollars per gallon while many others say it is about 4.3 dollars. However, all websites put the cost of 100LL avgas at around 5.1 dollars. I assume the 4.3 figure includes the additional charge of refuelling at the airport but I haven't found anything that mentions this (if it's true). But do airlines pay this price or do they refuel their planes by themselves and purchase the fuel wholesale at $1.5 dollars per gallon thereby minimising refuelling cost? And if so, can general aviation aircraft do the same - buy the 100LL fuel at wholesale for a cheaper price and fuel their own planes?

In practice, what is the difference between the price that airlines pay for Jet-A1 and what general aviation pilots are paying?

Comment: Prices vary widely around the world, you need to focus this down to an area or ask something specific.

Comment: I was referring to the national averages in the U.S.

Comment: Skyvector has current prices of both in USA. Open the Layers toolbox and under the FBOs tab select which ones you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

The prices vary widely in the US depending on where you are and the type of airport you are at. Major class B airports and class D satellite airports in big cities tend to have the highest prices I have ever seen when flying. [Most prices are listed publicly](https://www.airnav.com/fuel/local.html) if you would like to look up anything specific [but this study has some decent summary data for airports they included](https://www.gao.gov/assets/710/702906.pdf) that may interest you:

[image]

[As for why the price is different, its mostly a supply and demand issue.](https://generalaviationnews.com/2012/10/14/why-does-100ll-cost-so-much/) The country (and for that matter the globe) simply uses a *lot* less 100L than it does Jet A.

If you have a place to store 100LL you sure can buy it in bulk but most guys putting around in a 172 don't have that kind of luxury.

Comment: This is surprising. I thought Jet A was substantially cheaper, not a little bit cheaper.

Comment: Do these numbers include taxes? At least here in Germany, the fuel is taxed differently for private vs. commercial use, which makes up most of the difference, IIRC.

Comment: @JohnK One can negotiate *substantially* lower prices when buying in bulk, and jets (and especially airlines) use a lot more fuel than pistons. That leads to a much greater difference in actual prices paid than retail pricing would indicate.

Comment: The Airnav site you linked to is a very good source for fuel costs.  I've used it extensively when planning flights.  I'll usually top off my tanks at whatever FBO has cheaper fuel when I'm flying around the local areas since the airport that I'm based at is most definitely NOT one of the cheaper ones.

Comment: Then there's the 65 cents/gal difference between the major airport  and the mostly GA airport 20 miles south.  And at that airport, there's a 1.14 dollar/gal difference between the FBO coming out to your plane with a fuel truck, and you taxiing up to the self-serve pump: https://www.airnav.com/airport/KCXP/MOUNTAIN_WEST

Comment: @StephenS  They also purchase futures contracts for their bulk fuel to provide more stability for planning purposes.

Comment: As you said, the national average for Jet-A1 is listed at around 4.8 dollars. So why do some websites list its price around 1.5 dollars? Is it because of airline negotiations or just incorrect? - https://www.airlines.org/argus-us-jet-fuel-index/ - https://www.iata.org/en/publications/economics/fuel-monitor/ (I think this one is international though)